# Add link to a part of the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I am new with `ASP.NET` (`C#`). I have `Calander` control at the middle of my page, when I select any day within that calender, the page seems to refresh and gets back to show the upper part of it. I want to be at the middle of the page when I try to select any date. How to do that?

Comment: Since you are using a `asp.net` calendar which runs on server side, causes a page refresh. Have a look [this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). Alternatively, you can try [Ajax-Calendar](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/calendar/calendar.aspx)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty , I don't want to change that calender, I want to deal with it for my knowledge.

Comment: Then only option I can see is to use the same control inside a [UpdatePanel](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/) which will not cause a page refresh